find the number of quadrilteral-faces of a polyhedron if all of its faces are quadriliteral or hexagonal if in the vertices 3 faces meet
Given a polyhedron such that each of its faces is either a quadrilateral or a hexagon, and in each of its vertices 3 faces meet, find the number of quadrilateral-shaped faces.
Here is what I tried:
let $v$ be the number of vertices, $e$ the number of edges, $f_4$ the number of quadrilaterals and $f_6$ the number of hexagons.
We can do a system of equations:
$$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      2e=\sum_{v \in V} deg(v)=3v\\
      2e=4\cdot f_4 + 6 \cdot f_6 \\
      v-e+f_4 + f_6 = 2
    \end{cases}\,.
\end{equation}
I tried to solve it and couldn't find $f_4$, so I might be missing some equation. Can I use another equation to find $f_4$?

As we also have $3v = 4f_4 + 6f_6$ (based on the first and second equations), we can substitute this and the second equation into the third equation:
$$\begin{gather}
\frac{4f_4+6f_6}{3} - 2f_4 - 3f_6 + f_4 + f_6 = 2 \\
\frac{4f_4}{3} + \color{blue}{2f_6} - 2f_4 - \color{blue}{3f_6} + f_4 + \color{blue}{f_6} = 2  \\
\frac{f_4}{3} = 2 \implies f_4 = 6
\end{gather}$$
Which implies a hexagonal prism.
